# Android (Java) GregorianCalendar odd behavior

Tags: java, android, date, gregorian-calendar

I have problem with java `Date` type. Why in my code `days` and `days1` both equall 88?

```
GregorianCalendar dateNow = new GregorianCalendar(2014,03,31);
GregorianCalendar dateFirstDay = new GregorianCalendar(2014,01,01);
long diffInMillies = dateNow. getTimeInMillis() - dateFirstDay. getTimeInMillis();
int days = (int) (diffInMillies / (1000*60*60*24));

GregorianCalendar dateNow1 = new GregorianCalendar(2014,04,01);
GregorianCalendar dateFirstDay1 = new GregorianCalendar(2014,01,01);
long diffInMillies1 = dateNow1. getTimeInMillis() - dateFirstDay1. getTimeInMillis();
int days1 = (int) (diffInMillies1 / (1000*60*60*24));
```

Comment: (As an aside, you realize you're finding the difference between "April 31st" and February 1st, right? Months are 0-based in Calendar...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you are giving dateNow a month of 03, which means it is taking it as April, since it starts the month from 0. 0=Jan;1=Feb etc.
Now, you are giving day of month as 31. Since April only has 30 days, it is incrementing and treating the date as 1 May, which is same as your dateNow1.

Hence the same values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is day's zero based too?

Answer (score 3):

It's the expected behavior, infact:

```
GregorianCalendar dateNow = new GregorianCalendar(2014,03,31);
```

represents the same date as

```
GregorianCalendar dateNow1 = new GregorianCalendar(2014,04,01);
```

This is because months count start from `0`, so `03` is April and not March.
Visit [Official GregorianCalendar JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28int,%20int,%20int%29) for more info on constructors usage and other.

Comment: Is day's zero based too?

Comment: No,  DAY_OF_MONTH starts from 1